# atlassian jira password Encodes

Tags: java, jira, password-hash

will need to get  the same hash password saved in jira database for a user already stored.
I try to use Atlassian’s PBKDF2-based Hash but I can't generate the same hash .
is it possible to generate the same hash if yes how can I do it and   what is the algorithm used in hashing

Comment: Why not use the change user password REST endpoint? https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/8.13.13/#user-changeUserPassword

Comment: i want to use same  password used by  jira  in  another  application